# BouncyCastle in-memory PGP encryption in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, bouncycastle, pgp

I've been trying to use the BouncyCastle library to do PGP encryption/decryption. I have some code that I need to modify to use streams only - no files.

I tried removing the PgpUtilities.WriteFileToLiteralData() and then making it return a stream, but it didn't work (output stream was empty).

To be more clear here is what the method should be:

```
public static Stream EncryptFile(MemoryStream inputStream, PgpPublicKey encKey, bool withIntegrityCheck)
```

Here is the code I need to modify:

```
private static void EncryptFile(Stream outputStream, string fileName, PgpPublicKey encKey, bool armor, bool withIntegrityCheck)
{

    if (armor)
        outputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(outputStream);

    try
    {
        MemoryStream bOut = new MemoryStream();
        PgpCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(
        CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);
        PgpUtilities.WriteFileToLiteralData(
        comData.Open(bOut),
        PgpLiteralData.Binary,
        new FileInfo(fileName));
        comData.Close();
        PgpEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(
        SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom());
        cPk.AddMethod(encKey);
        byte[] bytes = bOut.ToArray();
        Stream cOut = cPk.Open(outputStream, bytes.Length);
        cOut.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
        cOut.Close();
        if (armor)
            outputStream.Close();
    }

    catch (PgpException e)
    {

        Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
        Exception underlyingException = e.InnerException;
        if (underlyingException != null)
        {

            Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.Message);
            Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.StackTrace);

        }
    }
}

public void EncryptFile(string filePath, string publicKeyFile, string pathToSaveFile)
{
    Stream keyIn, fos;
    keyIn = File.OpenRead(publicKeyFile);
    string[] fileSplit = filePath.Split('\\');
    string fileName = fileSplit[fileSplit.Length - 1];
    fos = File.Create(pathToSaveFile + fileName + ".asc");
    EncryptFile(fos, filePath, ReadPublicKey(keyIn), true, true);
    keyIn.Close();
    fos.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I got it working. The code uses byte[] for input and output of both decryption and encryption - no files.

Here is the full class:

```
class PGP
{
    public PGP() { }

    /**
    * A simple routine that opens a key ring file and loads the first available key suitable for
    * encryption.
    *
    * @param in
    * @return
    * @m_out
    * @
    */
    public static PgpPublicKey ReadPublicKey(Stream inputStream)
    {
        inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);
        PgpPublicKeyRingBundle pgpPub = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);
        //
        // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real
        // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
        //
        //
        // iterate through the key rings.
        //
        foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in pgpPub.GetKeyRings())
        {
            foreach (PgpPublicKey k in kRing.GetPublicKeys())
            {
                if (k.IsEncryptionKey)
                    return k;
            }
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("Can't find encryption key in key ring.");
    }

    /**
    * Search a secret key ring collection for a secret key corresponding to
    * keyId if it exists.
    *
    * @param pgpSec a secret key ring collection.
    * @param keyId keyId we want.
    * @param pass passphrase to decrypt secret key with.
    * @return
    */
    private static PgpPrivateKey FindSecretKey(PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec, long keyId, char[] pass)
    {
        PgpSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.GetSecretKey(keyId);
        if (pgpSecKey == null)
            return null;

        return pgpSecKey.ExtractPrivateKey(pass);
    }

    /**
    * Decrypt the byte array passed into inputData and return it as
    * another byte array.
    *
    * @param inputData - the data to decrypt
    * @param keyIn - a stream from your private keyring file
    * @param passCode - the password
    * @return - decrypted data as byte array
    */
    public static byte[] Decrypt(byte[] inputData, Stream keyIn, string passCode)
    {
        byte[] error = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("ERROR");

        Stream inputStream = new MemoryStream(inputData);
        inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);
        MemoryStream decoded = new MemoryStream();

        try
        {
            PgpObjectFactory pgpF = new PgpObjectFactory(inputStream);
            PgpEncryptedDataList enc;
            PgpObject o = pgpF.NextPgpObject();

            //
            // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
            //
            if (o is PgpEncryptedDataList)
                enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)o;
            else
                enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpF.NextPgpObject();

            //
            // find the secret key
            //
            PgpPrivateKey sKey = null;
            PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
            PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(
            PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn));
            foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pked in enc.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
            {
                sKey = FindSecretKey(pgpSec, pked.KeyId, passCode.ToCharArray());
                if (sKey != null)
                {
                    pbe = pked;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (sKey == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("secret key for message not found.");

                Stream clear = pbe.GetDataStream(sKey);
                PgpObjectFactory plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);
                PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();

                if (message is PgpCompressedData)
                {
                    PgpCompressedData cData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
                    PgpObjectFactory pgpFact = new PgpObjectFactory(cData.GetDataStream());
                    message = pgpFact.NextPgpObject();
                }
                if (message is PgpLiteralData)
                {
                    PgpLiteralData ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
                    Stream unc = ld.GetInputStream();
                    Streams.PipeAll(unc, decoded);
                }
                else if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
                    throw new PgpException("encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");
                else
                    throw new PgpException("message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");

                if (pbe.IsIntegrityProtected())
                {
                    if (!pbe.Verify())
                        MessageBox.Show(null, "Message failed integrity check.", "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                    else
                        MessageBox.Show(null, "Message integrity check passed.", "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(null, "No message integrity check.", "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                }

                return decoded.ToArray();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                if (e.Message.StartsWith("Checksum mismatch"))
                    MessageBox.Show(null, "Likely invalid passcode. Possible data corruption.", "Invalid Passcode", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else if (e.Message.StartsWith("Object reference not"))
                    MessageBox.Show(null, "PGP data does not exist.", "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else if (e.Message.StartsWith("Premature end of stream"))
                    MessageBox.Show(null, "Partial PGP data found.", "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                else
                    MessageBox.Show(null, e.Message, "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                Exception underlyingException = e.InnerException;
                if (underlyingException != null)
                    MessageBox.Show(null, underlyingException.Message, "PGP Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

                return error;
            }
        }

        /**
        * Encrypt the data.
        *
        * @param inputData - byte array to encrypt
        * @param passPhrase - the password returned by "ReadPublicKey"
        * @param withIntegrityCheck - check the data for errors
        * @param armor - protect the data streams
        * @return - encrypted byte array
        */
        public static byte[] Encrypt(byte[] inputData, PgpPublicKey passPhrase, bool withIntegrityCheck, bool armor)
        {
            byte[] processedData = Compress(inputData, PgpLiteralData.Console, CompressionAlgorithmTag.Uncompressed);

            MemoryStream bOut = new MemoryStream();
            Stream output = bOut;

            if (armor)
                output = new ArmoredOutputStream(output);

            PgpEncryptedDataGenerator encGen = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom());
            encGen.AddMethod(passPhrase);

            Stream encOut = encGen.Open(output, processedData.Length);

            encOut.Write(processedData, 0, processedData.Length);
            encOut.Close();

            if (armor)
                output.Close();

            return bOut.ToArray();
        }

        private static byte[] Compress(byte[] clearData, string fileName, CompressionAlgorithmTag algorithm)
        {
            MemoryStream bOut = new MemoryStream();

            PgpCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(algorithm);
            Stream cos = comData.Open(bOut); // open it with the final destination
            PgpLiteralDataGenerator lData = new PgpLiteralDataGenerator();

            // we want to Generate compressed data. This might be a user option later,
            // in which case we would pass in bOut.
            Stream pOut = lData.Open(
            cos,                    // the compressed output stream
            PgpLiteralData.Binary,
            fileName,               // "filename" to store
            clearData.Length,       // length of clear data
            DateTime.UtcNow         // current time
            );

            pOut.Write(clearData, 0, clearData.Length);
            pOut.Close();

            comData.Close();

            return bOut.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this saved me, I was able to translate the encrypt and compress methods into Java.

Comment: Hi, 
Did you then use this for the pure streaming method? I am trying to do the same... using streams instead of `byte[]`, and not `MemoryStream`, as I am working with **very large files**

Comment: I have a question, do I have to compress the encrypted output?

Comment: I know this is old, but you compress before encrypting. Since encryption results in few repeating results, compressing it after it is encrypted should not really compress it, making that step pointless. Compression removes redundant data, making the encryption more secure (identifiable repetition in encryption opens security holes).

Answer (score 5):

The accepted solution will work using the Bouncy Castle. However, for anyone looking for a simpler(?!) solution - take a look at the [PgpCore](https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore) nuget. It is a wrapper around Bouncy Castle just making it easier without needing to know it's internals.

```
// Encrypting a stream using PgpCore
using(PGP pgp = new PGP())
{
    using (FileStream inputFileStream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\keys\content.txt", FileMode.Open))
    using (Stream outputFileStream = File.Create(@"C:\TEMP\keys\content__encrypted2.pgp"))
    using (Stream publicKeyStream = new FileStream(@"C:\TEMP\keys\public.asc", FileMode.Open))
        pgp.EncryptStream(inputFileStream, outputFileStream, publicKeyStream, true, true);
}
```

Comment: The entire point of the question is to do it from memory

Comment: @Gaspa79 that is the beauty of Stream isn't it. It could be memory, it could be disk, it could be anything. That is what `pgp.EncryptStream` allows you to do and instead of passing a FileStream instance it could be a MemoryStream instance (or type that derives from Stream).

Comment: To compress the output file we need to set pgp.CompressionAlgorithm property (by default it is Uncompressed).

Comment: @Igor right now PgpCore has a bug if you try to encrypt the files from stream.

Comment: @virouz98 - could you provide a github issue link to the bug you are referring to?

Comment: @Igor [here you go](https://github.com/mattosaurus/PgpCore/issues/139)